# What's the typical values of "the second viscosity coefficient" of Air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

In Landau's book of fluid mechanics, the most general formula for stress looks like this:

[image]

let's call the eta in picture the first viscosity coefficient, call the zeta in the picture the second viscosity coefficient. I would like to know what are the typical values for these two coefficients for air. I am not sure if my memory is correct, but it seems that the second viscosity coefficient is often neglected.

By the way, I am not sure if questions regarding fluid mechanics and CFD are appropriate to ask here, or if there is a more suitable place to ask these questions, if you know, please recommend some to me, thanks.

Comment: For monatomic gases, zeta = 0.  See Bird et al, Transport Phenomena